# CORS Error, can't receive data from asp.net core backend

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, header, cors

I'm just getting started with web services. I created an asp.net core app with angular frontend.

I've already added CORS to my web service startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddDbContext<BuchverwaltungDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        //services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        //{
        //    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        //});
        services.AddCors();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors(options =>
        options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200/")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader());

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            //Swagger hier einbauen
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is how I try to the books in the angular Frontend:

```
getBooks() {
return this.http.get(this.baseURL + "/books")
.toPromise()
.then(res => this.books = res as Book[]);}
```

Somehow the Error still shows up on the console:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44302/api/books' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

When opening my API in the browser (https://localhost:44302/api/books), all the data show up correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

> The call to UseCors must be placed after UseRouting, but before UseAuthorization. For more information, see Middleware order.

So simply change your order of calling methods in `Configure` method.

##### Update based on comments

Also remove trailing slashes from origin. Ex.: `WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")` instead of `WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200/")`.

CORS header requires protocol and domain (`http://localhost:4200`), not endpoint (`http://localhost:4200/`).

Comment: i changed the order but still the same error..

Comment: which version of asp.net do you use?

Comment: im using .net 5.0

Comment: How does your order look like after the change? Try also removing `/` at the end of url to have `WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")`

Comment: it was because of the / at the end. You are a legend, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
services.AddCors(x => x.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
        }));
```

Try using this

Comment: still the same error